# JS-style dictionary initialization shortcut?

Tags: javascript, python

In JavaScript, you can initialize an object like so:

```js
{ a, b }
```

where `a` and `b` are declared variables. The initialization will use their values in the new object.

Is there anything similar in Python?

Comment: No, there isn't. You have to do `{"a": a, "b": b}`.

Comment: In Python, expression `{ a, b }` constructs a set, making up of two items: `a` and `b`. Suppose `a = 1` and `b = 2`, the result will a set of integers `1` and `2` aka `{ 1, 2 }`.

Comment: So... Are you satisfied with my answer? :)

Comment: @KaiserKatze, yes upvoted:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that python does not supports this. you can, however, write a library that somewhat mimics this functionality. See @KaiserKatze answer above

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own interpreter to undertake such requirement:

```
import re

# Set up local variable enviroment
#
# without the following assignment expressions,
# my lambda expression will return an empty dict
a = 1
b = 2

print((lambda str: (lambda f, z: { **f(globals(), z), **f(locals(), z) })(lambda s, t: { k: v for k, v in s.items() if t(k) },(lambda l: lambda k: k[0] is not '_' and k[-1] is not '_' and k in l)(re.sub(r'[\s\{\}]+', '', str).split(','))))('{ a, b }'))
```

And the output will be:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

However `convert` can only digest simple use cases such as yours, which has no nesting structures.

---

More human-reable version:

```
import re

example_string = '{ a, b }'

def convert_string_to_dict(example_string):
    list_of_variables = re.sub(r'[\s\{\}]+', '', example_string).split(',')

    def validate(key):
        return key[0] is not '_'                \
            and key[-1] is not '_'              \
            and key in list_of_variables

    def make_dict_from_environment(env):
        return { key: val for key, val in env.items() if validate(key) }

    merge_two_dicts = { **make_dict_from_environment(globals()), **make_dict_from_environment(locals()) }

    return merge_two_dicts

# Set up local variable enviroment
#
# without the following assignment expressions,
# `convert_string_to_dict('{ a, b }')` will return an empty dict
a = 1
b = 2

print(convert_string_to_dict(example_string))
```

Comment: Why would you do that with `lambda`s?!

Comment: Nothing fundamentally, but naming one is a definite anti-pattern. For all but the simplest cases, a proper `def` is orders of magnitude more readable. Also `convert` should probably error if the names aren't available, not return an empty object (per both the actual functionality in JS and the Zen of Python).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, I fixed the `convert` naming problem and recode a human-readable version down below.

Comment: However I think returning an empty dict is okay to live with, after all you can detect it by coding like `if not convert_string_to_dict('{ a, b }'): raise AssertionError()`.

Comment: @KaiserKatze Interesting, but how do you run convert_string_to_dict from within a function? how do you pass locals()?

Comment: @yigal `locals` and `globals` are built-in functions.

Comment: @KaiserKatze, yes I know about locals and globals built in functions. The thing is, if I want to use the convert_string_to_dict, that function will now have access to the locals of the calling function

Comment: What behaviour do you expect then? :)